# How can I easily get search context around search term with Typesense?

Tags: search, typesense

I currently use Typesense to search in an HTML database. When I search for a term, I would like to retrieve N characters before and N characters after the term found in search.

For example, I search for "query" and this is the sentence that matches:

**Let's repeat the query we made earlier with a group_by parameter**

I would like to easy retrieve a fixed number of letters (or words) before and after the term to show it in a presumably small area where the search results is retrieved, **without** breaking any words.

For this particular example, I would be showing:

**..repeat the *query* we made earlier..**

Is there a feature like this in Typesense?

I have checked Typesense's documents, without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're referring to is called snippets/highlights and it's enabled by default. You can control how many words are returned on either side of the matched text using the `highlight_affix_num_tokens` search parameter, documented under the table here: https://typesense.org/docs/0.23.1/api/search.html#results-parameters

> `highlight_affix_num_tokens`
>
> The number of tokens that should surround the highlighted text on each side. This controls the length of the snippet.